# A question about the maximum independent set in a graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint independent subsets in a graph $G$ such that $|A|=|B| \ge 1$, is it true that there must exist a maximum independent set $S_G$ of $G$ which satisfies $S_G\cap(A\cup B)=A \text{ or }B$? Here the maximum independent set means an independent set with the possible largest cardinality.

I'm trying to use contradiction,i.e., suppose that for every maximum independent set $S$ of $G$ we have $S\cap(A\cup B)\ne A$ and $S\cap(A\cup B)\ne B$, then I couldn't figure out what to do next, could any one help me out here?

Comment: Do you mean “maximum” or “maximal”? Many graphs don’t have a maximum independent set ($C_4$ has two, for example)

Comment: @Stella It's "maximum".

Comment: Also, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $A\cap B=\emptyset$, so this amounts to asking if there exists an independent set that’s neither $A$ nor $B$. This is obviously the case. You seem to have gone wrong somewhere in the phrasing of the question.

Comment: @Stella I can't see why it's obvious. Do you assume that every independent set in $G$ can generate a maximum independent set?

Comment: Also, your work uses the phrase “for every maximum independent set.” This is not needed, as if a maximum independent set exists it is unique. There is no graph with two maximum independent sets.

Comment: @Stella I'm really sorry that I put the $\cap$ and $\cup$ notions in the wrong place. I just corrected them. Plz read it again.

Comment: There are different conventions regarding "maximum" and "maximal".  According to one, a maximal independent set is one that is not a proper subset of another independent set.  A maximum independent set is such that no other independent set is larger.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Interesting, I didn’t realize there was that ambiguity. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Mark I have edited my answer to answer your new question.

Comment: @ Fabio Somenzi The one you referred to is exactly what I mean. Are there any other definitions on these two concepts?

Comment: @Mark I was thinking that a maximum independent set is one where the set is a maximal independent set, and no other maximal independent sets exist. A maximal independent set is then defined to be an independent set of the largest possible cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a counter example we need a graph $G$ and two sets $A$ and $B$ such that every maximum independent set contains elements from $A$ and elements from $B$. This will be a counter example because then the intersection will contain elements from $A$ (and therefore cannot equal $B$) and also contain elements from $B$ (and therefore cannot equal $A$).

If $G$ contains an isolated vertex, that must be in any maximum independent set. If there are two isolated vertices we can put one in $A$ and one in $B$ and therefore force elements of both sets to be in every maximum independent set. Therefore there are graphs for which there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that there does not exist a $S_G$ with the required properties.